# Codeigniter join two tables in model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to join 2 tables in my model but it doesn't work.

This is my model now

```
function list_get($id){
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('lists', array('list_id'=>$id));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

How do I join the lists `list_items` and `lists` where `'list_id=>$id'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this one.

```
$this->db->select('*')
     ->from('lists')
     ->join('list_items', 'list_items.list_id = lists.id') 
     ->where('list_id', $id);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

---

Reference

- [query_builder](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this to get you started,

```
    $this->db->select('*')
         ->from('lists')
         ->join('list_items', 'list_items.list_id = lists.id') 
         ->where('list_id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already answer.

but you can give 
https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model
this a try.
including the thing you want + many many features

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function CartOrderAll(){
    $this->db->select('*')
         ->from('tbl_order')
         ->join('tbl_order_person', 'tbl_order.order_person_id = tbl_order_person.order_person_id', 'left')
         ->group_by('tbl_order_person.order_person_id')
         ->order_by('tbl_order.order_date','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please try to elaborate a little as to why this is a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('user_registration');
$this->db->join('info', 'info.User_Id = user_registration.User_Id','left outer');
```